# Cocoa Development - Having trouble loading local XML files when running from device

Tags: iphone, xml, cocoa-touch, ios

I have a program that runs perfectly fine when I run on the simulator, but it won't run from the device at all. Part of the initial run involves loading a few XML files into core data and it seems that these files are not being found when running on the device.

Here is the beginning of the routine that loads the file. Any help is much appreciated.

```
- (BOOL) checkForUpdate:(NSString *)entityName {

    NSArray *thisObjectArray = nil;
    NSDate *thisEntityDate = nil;
    BOOL returnVal = NO;

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"AppData" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSError *error;
    NSArray *appDataArray = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    [fetchRequest release];

    AppData *thisAppData = [appDataArray objectAtIndex:0];

    if ([entityName isEqualToString:@"Features"]) {
        thisEntityDate = thisAppData.FeaturesUpdated;
    }
    else if ([entityName isEqualToString:@"DisplayTypes"]) {
        thisEntityDate = thisAppData.DisplayTypesUpdated;
    }
    else if ([entityName isEqualToString:@"Sections"]) {
        thisEntityDate = thisAppData.SectionsUpdated;
    }


    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:entityName ofType:@"xml"];
    NSData *xmlData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    GDataXMLDocument *doc = [[GDataXMLDocument alloc] initWithData:xmlData options:0 error:&error];

    if (doc != nil) { 
        // process information - this code is not being called because doc is returning nil
    }


[xmlData release];
[doc release];

   return returnVal;
}
```

Comment: Mind the case sensitivity. The device is case sensitive, whilst the simulator is not.

Comment: Have you tried NSLogging the xmlData as a string when running from device?

Comment: Thank you - the issue was actually case sensitivity. I hadn't realized that there was a discrepancy there, but that did the trick.

Comment: I'll post that as an answer in case you want to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mind the case sensitivity. The device is case sensitive, whilst the simulator is not.